# knex with pg_column_size in the returning function

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

- Knex: 0.95.12
- Database: PostgreSQL 11.7
- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) (official Docker image)
- Node: v12.22.6

Is it possible for [knex](https://knexjs.org/) to return the results of a call to `pg_column_size` via the [returning](https://knexjs.org/#Builder-returning) function call?

This works in native SQL:

```
create table "MyTable"
(
    "ID"       serial
        constraint "MyTable_pkey"
            primary key,
    "MyColumn" varchar
);

INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("MyColumn")
VALUES ('Whatever')
RETURNING "ID", pg_column_size("MyColumn");
```

Result:

```
+--+--------------+
|ID|pg_column_size|
+--+--------------+
|4 |9             |
+--+--------------+
```

But I suppose I'm not surprised that knex expects an actual column to return when doing ...

```
.returning(["ID", 'pg_column_size("MyColumn")'])
```

Result:

```
ERROR:  column "pg_column_size("MyColumn")" does not exist ...
```

I am hoping for a way to return that data without resorting to a subsequent select query after the insert.

Answer (score 1):

A fix is to use knex.raw() inside the returning array like this:

```
.returning(["ID", source.raw('pg_column_size("MyColumn")')])
```

Worked for me on a similar issue where i had to run a query in there.

(Just in case, make sure to be on Knex latest version - as today - v1.0.7)